# Radio validation with Javascript not working

Tags: javascript

I have some HTML and Javascript code. Whenever I test it, I get an error that my function is not defined. I don't know why this is happening. I have checked through the code and I don't see anything that seems to be wrong with it.

```js
function proccessSecurity(el) {
    if (el.value == "none") {
        document.getElementById('tid-password').style = "display: none;";
        document.getElementById('tid-users-allowed').style = "display: none;";
    }

    if (el.value == "password") {
        document.getElementById('tid-password').style = "display: block;";
        document.getElementById('tid-users-allowed').style = "display: none;";
    }

    if (el.value == "specific") {
        document.getElementById('tid-password').style = "display: none;";
        document.getElementById('tid-users-allowed').style = "display: block;";
    }

}
```

```html
<textarea rows="20" cols="100" id="tid-text-area"></textarea><br><br>

Security<br>
<input onchange="processSecurity(this);" type="radio" name="security" value="none" checked> No security.</input><br>
<input onchange="processSecurity(this);" type="radio" name="security" value="password"> Allow only users with a password.</input><br>
<input onchange="processSecurity(this);" type="radio" name="security" value="specific"> Allow only specified users.</input><br>
<input style="display: none;" type="password" id="tid-password"><br><br>
<input style="display: none;" type="text" id="tid-users-allowed"><br><br>
```

Comment: Typo. Remove the second letter "c" from `proccessSecurity` where you define your function so it matches what you have in the `onchange` in your HTML.

Comment: Voting to close as offtopic because the issue is a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is typo in code you should change

**proccessSecurity**

to

**processSecurity**

and it will not show function not defined

Answer (score 2):

Your inline handler is `processSecurity`, but your function is defined as `proccessSecurity`. Simple typo.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function proccessSecurity(el) {
 if (el.value == "none") {
  document.getElementById('tid-password').style = "display: none;";
  document.getElementById('tid-users-allowed').style = "display: none;";
 }

 if (el.value == "password") {
  document.getElementById('tid-password').style = "display: block;";
  document.getElementById('tid-users-allowed').style = "display: none;";
 }

 if (el.value == "specific") {
  document.getElementById('tid-password').style = "display: none;";
  document.getElementById('tid-users-allowed').style = "display: block;";
 }

}
```

```html
<textarea rows="20" cols="100" id="tid-text-area"></textarea><br><br>

Security<br>
<input onchange="proccessSecurity(this);" type="radio" name="security" value="none" checked> No security.</input><br>
<input onchange="proccessSecurity(this);" type="radio" name="security" value="password"> Allow only users with a password.</input><br>
<input onchange="proccessSecurity(this);" type="radio" name="security" value="specific"> Allow only specified users.</input><br>
<input style="display: none;" type="password" id="tid-password"><br><br>
<input style="display: none;" type="text" id="tid-users-allowed"><br><br>
```

`<input onchange="processSecurity(this);"` => `<input onchange="proccessSecurity(this);"`

You missed 'c' of proccess.